# Write to multiple bluetooth Peripherals from Central

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, core-bluetooth

I've searched SO for help on this and haven't found anything that will answer, address or get me pointed in the right direction so I've decided to post my issue.

I have a BT Central app running on an Apple TV. I have a peripheral app running on an iPhone and iPad.

The central app is able to connect to both peripheral devices just fine. I'm able to transfer all kinds of data to the central app and have control over all of the phases of the session (didDiscoverPeripheral, didDiscoverServices, didDiscoverChracteristics, etc.) All the delegate methods on both central and peripheral sides are behaving exactly as they should.

When the central app connects to a peripheral and it discovers the "writable" characteristic it sends (writes) an NSString to the peripheral with something like "Hi iPad, you've connected to central" or "Hi iPhone you've connected to central". In doing this I know that everyone is connected, discovered, processed and a reference to the peripherals is saved. None of this is an issue and behaves exactly as is documented by Apple.

On the central app I have a UIButton that performs a write to all of the connected peripherals. I attempt to loop through the connected peripherals and write something to each one inside the loop. Unfortunately only the last connected peripheral receives the written data.

I have a nice NSDictionary of all of the peripheral information and object that I enumerate through. I've even based the loop on the 
retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices method. My peripherals all use a custom class for their delegate so I know I'm not crossing the same delegate with multiple peripherals.

Inside the loop I can see that the peripheral is connected, the characteristic I'm targeting has writeWithResponse properties and write permissions. No reference to the peripheral has been lost or released. Everything maps out and looks great.

I just can't write to all the connected peripherals from inside a loop. I've tried queuing up the writes in an NSOperation and or dispatch_async in case it's a timing thing but nothing is working.

If the iPad is the last connect peripheral it gets the write. If the iPhone connect last then it gets the write. The last connected peripheral is the only clue I've got to go on but I'm just not seeing the problem.

At this point I'm out of sticks and carrots and several days of googling and SO searching. Sorry for the long post but I wanted to explain and also show that I'm not just asking out of laziness but have sincerely tried everything I know.

Thanks for any help.

Added relevant code:

`-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *) advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {`

```
//it's in range - have we already seen it?
if([self findPeripheralMatching:peripheral.identifier] == nil) {

    //hack if the advertisingData local name or the peripheral GATT name is NULL
    NSDictionary *dict = [self cleanupAdvertisementData:peripheral advertisementData:advertisementData];
    if(dict == nil) {
        [self stop];
        [self start];
        return;
    }

    //save a local copy of the peripheral, so CoreBluetooth doesn't get rid of it
    XCBluetoothPeripheralDictionary *obj = [[XCBluetoothPeripheralDictionary alloc] init];
    obj.peripheral = peripheral;
    obj.advertisementData = dict;

    [self.peripheralDictionary setObject:obj forKey:[peripheral.identifier UUIDString]];

    //and connect is not connected...
    if(peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateDisconnected) {
        [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }

}       //findPeripheralMatching
```

}       //didDiscoverPeripheral

`-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {`

```
//make sure we get the discovery callbacks
XCBluetoothPeripheral *pd = [[XCBluetoothPeripheral alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
pd.subscriptionDictionary = self.subscriptionDictionary;
peripheral.delegate = pd;

//save a copy of the XCPeripheral object
[self.peripheralDictionary objectForKey:[peripheral.identifier UUIDString]].delegate = pd;

//discover and search only for services that match our service UUID
[peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:self.serviceUUID]]];

//notify the delegate we connected
XC_SelectorAssert(@selector(bluetoothCentralDidConnect:), self.delegate)
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(bluetoothCentralDidConnect:)]) {
    XCBluetoothPeripheralDictionary *dict = [self.peripheralDictionary objectForKey:[peripheral.identifier UUIDString]];
    [self.delegate bluetoothCentralDidConnect:dict];
} else {
    NSAssert(NO, XCMissingSelectorForProtocol);
}
```

}       //didConnectPeripheral

`-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {`

```
if(error) {
    [self callbackError:error];
    return;
}

//again, we loop through the array, and if the characteristic matches
//whats in the subscriptionDictionary then we subscribe to it
for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

    if([self isDesiredCharachteristic:characteristic.UUID]) {

        [peripheral discoverDescriptorsForCharacteristic:characteristic];

        if(characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify) {
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }

        if(characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyRead) {
        }

        if(characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite) {

            NSLog(@"Writing value to %@ - %@", peripheral.identifier, peripheral.name);

            NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ connected to %@",
                                peripheral.name,
                                [XCUtilities deviceName]];

            [peripheral writeValue:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                 forCharacteristic:characteristic
                              type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
        }

        if(characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse) {
        }

        [self.subscriptionDictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)characteristic.UUID].characteristic = characteristic;

    }       //if isMatching

}       //for CBCharacteristic
```

}       //didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService

The following method is called from an IBAction

`-(void)writeValueToCharacteristic:(CBUUID *)cbuuid value:(NSString *)string {`

```
//get a reference to the characteristic we specified
CBCharacteristic *chr = [self findCharacteristicMatching:cbuuid];
XC_CBCharacteristicAssert(chr)

//enumerate through the discovered peripherals
[self.peripheralDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, XCBluetoothPeripheralDictionary *obj, BOOL *stop){

    XC_CBPeripheralAssert(obj.peripheral)
    if(obj.peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {

        //check the properties
        if(chr.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse ||
           chr.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite) {

            NSLog(@"Writing value to:\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@",
                  key,
                  obj.advertisementData,
                  obj.peripheral.name,
                  obj.peripheral.delegate,
                  obj.peripheral);

            NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [obj.peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:chr
                                  type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
        } else {

            [self localError:XC_BTErrorPermissionWritable description:XCErrorWritingCharacteristic];

        }

    }       //is connected

}];
```

}       //writeValueToCharacteristic

I would think that if something were wrong with the way I'm saving the peripherals or my custom dictionary or the way I'm using this stuff then my writes would fail for all peripherals and not just one of the two I'm testing with from inside a loop. And I know I'm connected and discovered and all is well because when central initially processes these peripherals it writes to each one as sort of a confirmation that they are indeed ready to go.

`- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests {`

```
[peripheral respondToRequest:[requests objectAtIndex:0] withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];

CBATTRequest *aRequest = requests[0];
NSData *aData = aRequest.value;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:aData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self logToDelegate:string];
```

}

`-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
            error:(NSError *)error {`

```
if(error) {
    [self callbackError:error];
    return;
}

[self logToDelegate:@"didWriteValueForCharacteristic"];
```

}       //didWriteValueForCharacteristic

Comment: `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` is called when you attempt to write?

Comment: Please show us relevant parts of your code, maybe there's a mistake you were unable to catch. Also, have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652179/how-to-write-data-to-multiple-bluetooth-le-slaves-simultaneously-on-corebluetoot.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to post any meaningful code because SO is limiting my comments to ~500 characters so I'm foo bar on that notion. I can say that my code follows apple's docs on core bluetooth and also most examples that I've seen here on SO. As far as the link you have provided, yes I did read that and I'm doing the same thing. Really it boils down to - Yes I can write to each peripheral when I connect and discover - No I can only write to the last peripheral to connect when attempting to write to all connected peripherals inside a loop which gets executed when I tap a button on the UI

Comment: Whoops. I see that I can edit my question and add code.

Comment: @xcodeguy can you show the code for `peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests:` and `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:`? I guess it's a good starting point.

Comment: Sure. I have added the two callback methods to my question.